# Python Subprocess [Errno 2] No such file or directory when calling subprocess.run()

Tags: python, flask, g++

I have a simple python web application made with flask. It compiles and runs the given c++ files on given input. Upon receiving the inputs from front-end, I use this function to compile and run the given file.

```
exec_id = get_unique_identifier(data["user_id"])
code = data["code"]
input_data = data["input"]
code_path = file_ops.write_code(code, data["lang"], exec_id)
logging.info("Code written to "+code_path)
#compile the code
logging.info("Compiling the code")
cmd = ['g++',code_path,'-o',exec_id]
logging.info("Command is : "+" ".join(cmd))
try:
    compile_code=subprocess.run(cmd, stderr=PIPE)
    has_compiled = compile_code.returncode
except Exception as e:
    return {"status": "server Error", "output" : e}
compiled_file_path = './'+exec_id
```

`file_ops.write_code` is a utility function which takes input code, extension as input and writes the code in a file in the same directory. The code runs alright in local environment, However, In production server with nginx, The code never gets compiled and I get the following error(After a big traceback)

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g++'
```

I tried the following things

- Giving Absolute Path in code
- passing `shell=True` in subprocess.run

Does this have something to do with Configuration with Nginx ? I'm running this application with gunicorn and nginx on Ubuntu VPS. If I run the code in development environment on vps, it runs without any error.